# Database connection phpmyadmin

Tags: php, mysql

I'm working for an e-commerce that has the db on phpmyadmin. In another website I'd like to connect to that database. I have password, username and db name, so I'm using this "connection string":

```
<?php
$nomehost = "localhost";    
$nomeuser = "user";         
$password = "pass";
// connection
$conn=mysql_connect($nomehost,$nomeuser,$password);
if (!$conn) exit ("Error connection<br>");

// db name
if (!mysql_select_db("db_name",$conn)) exit("Error db name<br>");
?>
```

The result is "Error db name". What can I do? Have I to set some oprion in the phpmyadmin?

Comment: Does that website also run on a different server? Than the problem is pretty obvious.

Comment: Yes, it runs on a different server. I'm working at home and the server is in the firm.

Comment: `mysql` functions are deprecated.Please better to use `mysqli` or `pdo`

Comment: change `$nomehost = "localhost";` to `$nomehost = "mysite.com:3306";` assuming your mysql runs on that port.

Comment: You will have to open the MySQL port for public access on your firewall and server. Your connection string will no longer be localhost but rather the public IP of the internet router.

Comment: Opening up your MySQL installation to the public is probably a bad idea unless you actually understand the security ramifications of doing so and how to harden and protect your server against attacks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all:
this error is caused by the fact that you are selecting the wrong database in your MySql server. Is your db called db_name???

EDIT: based on the comments you are making: is the server that hosts the php page the same as the mysql server?

Then: 
phpmyadmin is just a tool to connect and handle MySql databases and is not a database server itself.

Last but most important: 
**you are using a deprecated library (mysql) in php to connect to a MySql server.** Please consider moving to mysqli or better to PDO

Comment: Values are just example.

One site is hosted on Altervista, the e-commerce in another one.

Is there a solution or is impossible to do?

Comment: See @MonkeyZeus comment on your question then. And take note on the informations I provided you. It is better to start with the right step if you are new to PHP and MYSQL :)